# SQL Syntax error on named temp-table

Tags: mysql, sql

Could anyone give me a hint, why the following query throws a syntax error?

```
SELECT *  
  FROM 
     (
       ( SELECT cu.ID id
              , name
              , ego_id
              , u.fb_id 
           FROM contact_users cu 
           JOIN users u 
             ON cu.ego_id = u.ID
       ) temp 
    LEFT 
    JOIN fb_user 
      ON temp.fb_id = fb_user.user_fb_id
     ) T4

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T4'...
```

If I remove `T4` everthing is fine.

I am using MySQL 5.5.47

Comment: Just JOIN the 3 tables directly why the arcane subqueries

Comment: the inner table is very big, so a select might be a good choice, but nevertheless, a three table join does not solve the syntax problem

Comment: ***Why the following query throws a syntax error?*** Because T4 has no select or from.  remove the initial `(` and the Ending `) T4`   You can't alias a resultset if one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

***Why the following query throws a syntax error?***

Because you can't alias an inline view if one doesn't exist.

When you remove T4, the engine just see's ()'s for order of operation.  When you add the alias it assumes a well formed inline view exists and thus looks for the proper syntax (At least SELECT and FROM) which do not exist.

Put simply:

The alias T4 has no select or from; to resolve this:

- add them
- remove the initial `(` and the Ending `) T4` (they are not needed)
- refactor the SQL (why the inline view in the first place? it's not needed.)

***MORE DETAIL***

Your Temp alias works because it is a complete and accurate query that can run on it's own.

```
SELECT cu.ID id
              , name
              , ego_id
              , u.fb_id 
           FROM contact_users cu 
           JOIN users u 
             ON cu.ego_id = u.ID
```

WHERE AS:

```
( SELECT cu.ID id
          , name
          , ego_id
          , u.fb_id 
  FROM contact_users cu 
  JOIN users u 
    ON cu.ego_id = u.ID
) temp 
LEFT 
JOIN fb_user 
  ON temp.fb_id = fb_user.user_fb_id
```

Is not a complete and accurate SQL statement to generate a result set. As You can see this is missing keywords 'SELECT' and 'FROM'.  I suppose you could eliminate the left join and it would work but I don't think that would meet result in the desired results.

By eliminating the T4, the engine isn't attempting to parse the data between the ()'s as a valid SQL statement, instead it just see's the ()'s as order of operation and since the () don't matter on the outer portion the engine doesn't perceive a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

Either have `Query 1` or `Query 2`

Query 1

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT cu.ID as id, name, ego_id, u.fb_id 
                FROM contact_users as cu 
                JOIN users as u 
                 ON cu.ego_id = u.ID
            ) temp 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN fb_user 
            ON temp.fb_id = fb_user.user_fb_id
    ) T4
```

Query 2

```
SELECT cu.ID as id, name, ego_id, u.fb_id, fb_user.* 
FROM contact_users as cu 
JOIN users as u 
 ON cu.ego_id = u.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fb_user 
 ON u.fb_id = fb_user.user_fb_id
```

I prefer **Query 2**

Comment: Even if contact_users contains 30 columns? I thought it might be a good idee, too select before the join

Comment: The question was 'why [does] the following query [throw] a syntax error?', not 'how can I get a functioning query'?

Comment: @Strawberry I hope on looking into `Query1`, the OP might have understood the issue in the query, he tried.

Comment: Well, I'm looking, and I don't understand 'why' from this.

Comment: @Strawberry It is not my fault if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Viki888 Strawberry is politely pointing out that you're answer while likely addressing the syntax error, does nothing to explain why this would work.  Nor does the answer you have explain why when he removes T4 it works, and when he adds T4 it doesn't.  Your answer address the syntax problem, but not the reason (root cause of) why the problem exists.